# Повторение слова во всплывающем сообщении дважды

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Заметил ошибку в сообщении (красненькое такое), когда хотел проголосовать за синонимы метки `юнит-тесты`:

> Для голосования за синонимы данной метки Вам не хватает репутации репутации по ней

Слово "репутации" два раза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[В Transifex это строка 627.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262211?qt=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Заодно:

- поменял «Вам» на «вам»,
- поменял репутацию на рейтинг, все-таки имено 5 рейтинга по метке нужно для голосования.
- сохранил в suggestions, создал задачу.

Теперь ждём, когда кто-нибудь с правами подтвердит правку.

> Для голосования за синонимы данной метки вам не хватает рейтинга по ней

Comment: Подтвердил правку. Спасибо!

Comment: Обновил строки в базе!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: вы вручную запускаете обновление базы из транзифекса или это происходит автоматически и регулярно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin  Вручную, но сами строки обновляются автоматически, после во время первой успешной сборки. Обычно, движок обновляется несколько раз в день.